# How do I use my Javascript library in the browser with ES6 + Webpack?

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6, webpack

I'm creating a library in ES6 that I want to call from a script tag in the HTML:

```js
class CoolElement {
 constructor() {
      
    }
    init() {
      return document.createElement('div');
    }
}

export default new CoolElement();
```

```html
<html>
<body>
 <div id="content"></div>
 <script type="module" src="../dist/coolelement.js"></script>
 <script>
  var element = CoolElement.init(); //Error! CoolElement does not exist!
  document.getElementById('content').addChild(element);
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I use Webpack with Gulp to convert it to es5 and bundle it to the dist folder. But when I require it on the page, there's no global CoolElement reference. How can I do this..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
   entry: "./entry.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "bundle.js",
        library: "home"
    },
```

**Add library: "home" in webpack config then**

```js
  var element = home.CoolElement.init();
  document.getElementById('content').addChild(element);
```

Comment: Ah, it wasn't working for me because i had <script type="module" src="..."> omitting the type="module" fixed it.